# how to load data after entering a viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewController that contains some GIF images,load these images cost a lot of memory ,so it takes me seconds to enter this viewController everytime,is there any way I can enter this viewCOntroller first,then load the data? I don't know NSThread will work or not.My english is poor,hope you can understand my question.Thx.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` not `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the easiest way is to use grand central dispatch

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ //enter a background thread
  UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]; //load image in background

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //return to main thread
      [[self imageView] setImage: img]; //set the imageViews image
  });
});
```

Comment: It works,there is no time-delay now :) But there's something wrong with my GIFS,that's another problem,so thank you!

Comment: Where to implement this? In view did load?

Comment: @bhavinramani yep, or `viewWillAppear`, would be inefficient to do it in `viewDidAppear` though as the delay in calling that function would just needlessly delay the loading of your images

Answer (score 1):

Just write your code in `viewDidAppear:` or use a thread in `viewDidLoad`

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Add your image creation code here e.g.
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Add code here to update the UI
        self.imageView = image;
    });
});
```

Comment: I use this method and change the priority to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,so it works well,thank you!  Can I accept two different answers?

Comment: No you can't accept two answer but surely you can upvote two answers

Comment: I only have 4 reputations,so I can't upvote any answer :(

Comment: I guess now you have enough :)

Comment: I have 14 reputation now! did you give me 10 ? :):):)

Comment: sorry,acturely I have 18 now,I checked the wrong place. Now I can upvote your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the loading of data inside the viewDidAppear method of your ViewController, so the View will appear at first without the GIFS, but as you loop getting each data, you can set the images to your view as they get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like that .

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ 

 // (BackGroungThred)  here you can  retrive the image from your sources . But do not update UI in backgroung thread ..

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

// (Main Thread) Update UI in main thread..

});

});
```

hope  it help you ..

Answer (score 1):

There are **Two options** for load data after entering in a view controller

1.NSOperationQueue

```
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
   // Background work
   UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Main thread work (UI usually)
    yourImageView.image = image;
}];
}];
```

2.Grand Central Dispatch(GCD)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
{
          // Background work  
          UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];          
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
          {
               // Main thread work (UI usually)  
               yourImageView.image = image;           

          });
});
```

For more details please refer the below links

[Link1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/)

[Link2](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569244/nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue-working-thread-vs-main-thread)

[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch)

[Link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651551/why-should-i-choose-gcd-over-nsoperation-and-blocks-for-high-level-applications)

[Link6](http://mskarki.blogspot.in/2012/03/nsthread-vs-nsoperationqueue-vs-gcd.html)

Comment: thank you ,both two options are simple and easy to implement :)

Comment: if my answer is very understandable and helpful for you,please tick my answer.