# How to show GET request in Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, get-request

My get request works only in command line NSLog.
I need to show a data in Label, but it doesn't works.

```
-(void)getRequest{

  NSURLSessionConfiguration *getConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *getSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: getConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
  NSURL * getUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/get"];
  NSURLSessionDataTask * getDataTask = [getSession dataTaskWithURL:getUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *getData, NSURLResponse *getResponse, NSError *getError) {
    if(getError == nil){
       NSString * getString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: getData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [self.label setText:getString];// doesn't work!
       NSLog(@"Data = %@",getString);}//  it works!!
       MainViewController*l=[[MainViewController alloc]init];

       [l getRequest];
    }
 ];

 [getDataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your label is nil or not? By placing `NSLog(@"Data = %@", self.label);` in the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*dataTaskWithURL* is not working on the main-thread and that's necessary to update your UI.

```
if (getError == nil) {
    NSString * getString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: getData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.label setText: getString];
        NSLog(@"Data = %@", getString);

    });

    }
```

This code will work fine for you.

You can also use:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self.label setText:getString];       
}];
```

Real more here [Why should I choose GCD over NSOperation and blocks for high-level applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651551/why-should-i-choose-gcd-over-nsoperation-and-blocks-for-high-level-applications/7654476#7654476)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not quite sure what the usage would be here...you are using `@getString`, which I think is the issue. You probably want to do something like:

```
[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:"Data = %@", getString];
```

That should have the same behavior as `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.label setText:someString];
});
```