# OperationQueue.main vs DispatchQueue.main

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, ui-thread

When you need to perform something on the main thread in the completion block of a networking task or an operation, which of these ways to get it would be the most appropriate and why?:

- `OperationQueue.main.addOperation`
- `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Check this links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651551/why-should-i-choose-gcd-over-nsoperation-and-blocks-for-high-level-applications/7654476#7654476 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch

Answer (score 17):

For details on the differences between the two types of queue, see Lion's answer.

Both approaches will work. However, `NSOperation` is mostly needed when more advanced scheduling (including *dependencies*, *canceling*, etc.) is required. So in this case, a simple

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { /* do work */ }
```

will be just fine. That would be equivalent to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* do work */ });
```

in Objective-C, which is also how I would do it in that language.

Comment: @Lion: I disagree with your choice of formatting all emphasized words with backticks as `code`. Please consider using underscores to make them _italic_ instead.

Answer (score 17):

**When to Use NSOperation**

The `NSOperation` API is great for encapsulating well-defined blocks of functionality. You could, for example, use an `NSOperation` subclass to encapsulate the login sequence of an application.

Dependency management is the icing on the cake. An operation can have dependencies to other operations and that is a powerful feature Grand Central Dispatch lacks. If you need to perform several tasks in a specific order, then operations are a good solution.

You can go overboard with operations if you are creating dozens of operations in a short timeframe. This can lead to performance problems due to the overhead inherent to the `NSOperation API`.

**When to Use Grand Central Dispatch**

`Grand Central Dispatch` is ideal if you just need to dispatch a block of code to a serial or concurrent queue.

If you don’t want to go through the hassle of creating an `NSOperation subclass` for a trivial task, then `Grand Central Dispatch` is a great alternative. Another benefit of `Grand Central Dispatch` is that you can keep related code together. Take a look at the following example.

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
// Process Response
...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    // Update User Interface
    ...
})
})
```

In the completion handler of the data task, we process the response and update the user interface by dispatching a closure (or block) to the main queue. This is necessary because we don’t know which thread the completion handler is executed on and it most likely is a background thread.

> Quoted verbatim from [this source](https://cocoacasts.com/choosing-between-nsoperation-and-grand-central-dispatch/)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, to download a largefile, ex. a zip file containing 100mp3 files, its good going with GCD? to download individual mp3 files, one after another, its good going with NSOperation. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, GCD uses DispatchQueue, NSOperationQueue is now OperationQueue

Answer (score 12):

> DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the system.

Reference : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue)

> The NSOperationQueue class regulates the execution of a set of Operation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task. Operations within the queue (but not yet executing) are themselves organized according to priority levels and inter-operation object dependencies and are executed accordingly. An application may create multiple operation queues and submit operations to any of them.

Reference : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue)

So, you should prefer `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you want to perform something on main thread from completion block of any network call. Especially when it is related to `UI Updates`! And If your task is complex, I mean if you require further operation on running task then you can go with `OperationQueue.main.addOperation` otherwise `DispatchQueue.main.async` will give more optimal performance comparatively!