# SWIFT - What's the difference between OperationQueue.main.addOperation and DispatchQueue.main.async?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, queue, operation, dispatch-queue

Sometimes I must do something on the main thread and its suggested to place the code inside a `OperationQueue.main.addOperation`.

Other times, its suggested to write the code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

What the difference between these two?

(There's a similar question title, but the content is mismatched.)

Comment: you might want to read this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764240/2299040

Comment: I find [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764666/1987726) quite helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OperationQueue.main vs DispatchQueue.main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764140/operationqueue-main-vs-dispatchqueue-main/40764666)

Answer (score 5):

I used 'DispatchQueue.main.async' when I perform any task in main thread like Update my APP UI . When you need to run a further operation or block in main thread you can use  'OperationQueue'. Check this article to know more about [OperationQueue](https://agostini.tech/2017/07/30/understanding-operation-and-operationqueue-in-swift/)

**OperationQueue**  *From Apple Doc*

> The NSOperationQueue class regulates the execution of a set of
>   Operation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation remains
>   in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing
>   its task. Operations within the queue (but not yet executing) are
>   themselves organized according to priority levels and inter-operation
>   object dependencies and are executed accordingly. An application may
>   create multiple operation queues and submit operations to any of them.

Example :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        calculate()
    }

    private func calculate() {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        let blockOperation = BlockOperation {

            var result = 0

            for i in 1...1000000000 {
                result += i
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.label.text = "\(result)"
                self.label.isHidden = false
            }
        }

        queue.addOperation(blockOperation)
    }

}
```

**DispatchQueue**  *From Apple Doc*

> DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item
>   submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the
>   system.

Example :

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { 
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return 
    }

    do {
        let heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heroes = heroes
            completed()
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

OperationQueue is just an objective C wrapper over Grand Central Dispatch (GCD / libdispatch).

If you are using OperationQueue, then you are implicitly using Grand Central Dispatch.

OperationQueue.main.addOperation therefore is using DispatchQueue.main.async under the hood. There is some overhead of using Objective C (OperationQueue) over a C API (GCD) so there is a slight performance gain for using GCD.

I recommend reading Brad Larson's answer on why he prefers GCD over OperationQueue but it is a debatable subject.

[NSOperation vs Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch#targetText=NSOperationQueue%20is%20objective%20C%20wrapper,implicitly%20using%20Grand%20Central%20Dispatch.&targetText=operation%20will%20not%20started%20until,dependencies%20return%20true%20for%20finished).